# Azure TimeSeries API call issue python requests

Tags: python, azure, api, python-requests

I need help making a time series api call using python requests.

My header and body look like the following :

```
header = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
body = {
            "getSeries": {
                "timeSeriesId": idstring.split(','),
                "searchSpan": {
                    "from": timefrom,
                    "to": timeto,
                }
            }
        }
```

My request command is :

```
data = requests.post(f"https://{fqdn}/timeseries/query?api-version=2018-11-01-preview&storeType=warmstore",
                             headers=header,
                             data=body)
```

If i send the header and body as are, I get "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: g. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n"

If i send them as body = json.dumps(json), there is no unexpected character problem, but I get the error message "'str' object has no attribute 'items'".

I have also tried a solution i found with a custom dictionary that has double quotes instead of the standard single but that didn't work either. Bit stumped as to what to do.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Very annoying as spent a good few hours googling random stuff trying to work it out. I even started implementing it in Julia!

Simple correction : json=body instead of data=body in the request call

```
data = requests.post(f"https://{fqdn}/timeseries/query?api-version=2018-11-01-preview&storeType=warmstore",
                             headers=header,
                             json=body)
```